# сохранение формы текста и состояния кнопки(котлин, андроид)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Подскажите, как используя фрагмент сохранить состояние кнопки и формы текста в TextView, при повороте экрана, если при этом необходимо создавать метод newInstance(), то как правильно это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того, что именно вы хотите сделать.
Можно просто запретить "пересоздание" Activity при повороте.
Для этого в Манифесте, на нужной вам Активити надо дописать

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
 <intent-filter>
```

Так же можно использовать:

1. ViewModel
2. savedInstanceState
3. sharedpreferences

любой из этих 3 способов подойдет вам, если надо пересоздать Активити с новой разметкой. с помощью этих методов вы сможете сохранить данные из вашего UI.